# Custom Authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I work with Laravel 5.2 and I built a personal website with a blog, but I did the authentication method using my own custom build. I did not want to use the authentication utility within Laravel.

Now my project is finished and I did some work putting the middleware to guard against unauthorized access. Do I have anything to fear or was it a bad idea all together.

Comment: Are you worried about your unauthorized middleware or your custom login?

Comment: My approach of creating my custom auth system. And whether the auth system is Laravel is preferable to any custom approach...

Comment: Maybe if you post some code to your question someone can provide a meaningful answer, some tips or comments about your code perhaps.